# Population of Jtable from Unix Output

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Please Help,

i am trying to populate the Jtable from the output of UNIX box, I am executing the hive sql through shell and able to see the output in string format. I am trying to see the below output in table format.

```
private void jButton1_actionPerformed() {
    if (textarea1.getText() == null || textarea1.getText().equals("")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(contentPane,"Please Enter Your Sql."); }
        else {
    String cmd = "/opt/ibm/biginsights/hive/bin/hive -e 'SET hive.cli.print.header=true; " + textarea1.getText() + "'";
    i=0;
    String sql =HiveJdbcClient;
    if (cmd != null) {

        int returnchannel = UnixConnection.getUnixChannel(
                UnixConnection.session, cmd);
        System.out.println("Return Status=" + returnchannel);
        if (returnchannel == 0) {
            resultPanel.removeAll();
            resultPanel.updateUI();
            resultPanel.add(scrollpane, 0);
            BufferedReader bf = null;
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            String line;
            rs = UnixConnection.getUnixChannel(UnixConnection.session, cmd)
            try {
                bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        UnixConnection.in));
                while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("Return value=" + line);
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                    rs [i] = sb;
                    i++;

                }
                System.out.println(sb);
                contentPane.updateUI();

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
            //JTable table = new JTable(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
            table.setTableHeader(null);

        }
    }
        }
}
```

Comment: a jtable wants a double array, or a datamodel object. Figure out how to get a double array out of the stuff you get back.

Comment: You do need a `TableModel`; you shouldn't need `updateUI()`.